# How to get the sub heading column in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, columnheader

[image: Expected Matrix in Power BI]

The above is the expected matrix in Power BI. I have to get the additional heading "MED" and "RX" for the columns "Paid" and "Unpaid" as shown in the matrix.

[image: Table Schema]

The above is the actual table schema, which is connected to get the data into the matrix.

How to get the column heading "MED" and "RX" in Matrix?

Answer (score 4):

You should put MED/RX and Paid/Unpaid attributes in separate columns, so make sure the data is transformed to look like this:

[image]

Then put `Insurance` to the rows of the matrix, `Type` and `Paid` as columns and `Values` as values, and enable the drill mode:

[image]